# controller integration test: how do I test the call of a method on an entity

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

How can I setup a controller test to test if the `doSomething` method is called on the $entity

```
    public function doSomething($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->Entities->get($id);
        $entity->doSomething();
    }
```

my `EntitesControllerTest` looks like this:

```
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $this->setupUser();
        $this->get('/entities/do-something/1');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
```

I suppose I have to work with a mock-object of the entity, but how can I do that, the first thing the controller is doing is writing over the `$entity` variable?

Comment: Pretty simple: Don't do business logic in controllers. Either do proper DDD or use methods in cakes table objects, or even better, create your own objects, that do all the operations and then just pass required information from the request to these methods.

Comment: You test your model/entity and its method in functional tests inside your Model layer. Then you only test the high level result of your controller level as a whole as 2nd step. Do not mix those.

Comment: @mark: I have a test for the `doSomething` method of my entity. But I want to make sure that this method is called at all. In the setup above I could remove the line `$entity->doSomething();` from the controller without the controller test failing (and my entity tests wouldn`t fail either).

Comment: @burzum: Why do you consider the example above to be "business logic in a controller"? Is calling methods on entities in a controller considered a taboo?

Comment: @DavidAlbrecht technically you can do it, but it's not a good way of doing it. It is obviously a business operation that happens here, that should not happen in a controller. $this->Service->doSomething($id); should encapsulate the whole operation. It makes testing harder, it couples your business logic to the controller and you can't re-use it in other places. Actually a good implementation makes your whole business logic or domain layer agnostic to any framework. But this is hard to archive with Cake.